# Umbraco 7.3 with azure ad

Tags: umbraco, azure-active-directory

does anyone know how to use Azure AD authentication for members in Umbraco 7.3?
Are there any examples or documentation how to implement Azure AD for authentication in Umbraco?

Thx in advance,
Anton

Comment: Hi Anton! I have just worked with https://www.jdibble.co.uk/blog/securing-umbraco-backoffice-with-azure-active-directory/ to get azure ad on umbraco.